# Remove query strings from static resources in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, add-filter

I'd like to remove query strings in wordpress, I've written:

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
$parts = explode( '?', $src );
return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

But I need to ignore one query string:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

How would I write that?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you don't want to remove version `3.4.1` which is contained in this URL `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&language=en%C2%AEion=US&ver=3.4.1`

```
function _remove_script_version($src) {
    preg_match(
        "#^(https?)://([.0-9a-zA-Z-]+)(/?.*?)([^/]*)$#",
        $src,
        $queryStringPartsArray
    );
    $endOfUrlArray = explode('?', $queryStringPartsArray[4]);
    $paramsArray = explode('&', $endOfUrlArray[1]);
    foreach($paramsArray as $param) {
        $parts = explode('=', $param);
        if(($parts[1] == "ver") && !preg_match("/3.4.1/", $parts[1])) {
            return $queryStringPartsArray[1]."://".
                   $queryStringPartsArray[2].
                   $queryStringPartsArray[3].
                   $endOfUrlArray[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the actual: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&language=en®ion=US&ver=3.4.1    It works to not give the google warning, but google maps does not work when I put in /maps/

Comment: Indeed I realize that I had not really understood your question.
I just updated my answer above.

Comment: OK, wow, thx for that, but still not working for me; any other thoughts on solutions to block this function from that one script?

Comment: I need more infos to help you. What is supposed to return the function `_remove_script_version()` ? Something like : `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` ? Cause I just noticed that your initial function is supposed to return the first part of your url splitted on the `?` character.

Comment: I just want the function not to run for one script; that script is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&language=en%C2%AEion=US&ver=3.4.1

Comment: it could match for ?ver
If ?ver, drop it, keep all else

Comment: function _remove_script_version( $src ){
  $txt='?ver';
  $re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re2='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; # Word 1
 if ($src=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $txt, $matches)) {
  $parts = explode( '?', $src );
  return $parts[0];
  }
 }
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );